# How to access multidimensional array by index in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like below in java-script

```
Result = [
  {"ID":1,"Type":"Pyramid","Phase":"One"},
  {"ID":2,"Type":"Pyramid","Phase":"Two"}
]
```

I tried accessing the individual values and was able to by the below code

```
alert(Result[0].ID) or alert(Result[0].Phase)
```

Is there a way to access this by index? like Result[0][1], i tried but getting [object][object]
also i need to access column count

Please help me

Comment: "i need to access column count": What does this mean? Do you mean how many objects there are in the array? `Result.length` will give you that.

Comment: @Andy `Result.length` will give him the row count.

Comment: @19greg96, to be fair the OP isn't very clear. If he wants the number of keys in the object he can use `Object.keys(Result[0]).length` for example if that's what he means by `column`...

Comment: @Andy true, OP did not specify which dimension meant columns or rows, however, I would speculate, that one would not name rows rather than columns

Comment: sorry for not clear, yes i wanted column length and i got it by Object.keys(Result[0]).length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```
alert(Result[0][Object.keys(Result[0])[0]]);
```

- `Result[0]` gets the first row
- `Object.keys(Result[0])` gets the keys in the first row
- `Object.keys(Result[0])[0]` gets the first column name.

`Object.keys(Result[0]).length` is the column count in the first row.

Also, objects are not indexed based on a linear integer index as arrays are, so assigning ordered numbers to the unordered list of keys is not right.

A two dimensional array would look like this:

```
Result = [
  [1,"Pyramid","One"],
  {2,"Pyramid","Two"}
]
```

in this case, you could address each field like so: `Result[row][col]` thus `Result[0][2]` would yield `One`.

To access fields in an array of object use the syntax you have provided. Also, why would you want to access the fields in your objects based on id? Or why would you not use an array of arrays?

Comment: I am getting Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'

Comment: That's because the answer is wrong. Try `Result[0][Object.keys(Result[0])[0]]`. But I wouldn't. Understanding the difference between objects and arrays is kinda key in JS.

Comment: @Andy thank you! and sorry for not trying my code prior to posting, also, you are right, it is key, but posting that as a solution to the problem would solve nothing

Comment: I like your answer more than others as i dont have to convert my original data.. Thanks much

Answer (score 2):

You have array of object and by using for loop you can easily access all element value.

try following

```
  function getValue() {
   var keys ;
   var Result = [{"ID":1,"Type":"Pyramid","Phase":"One"},  {"ID":2,"Type":"Pyramid","Phase":"Two"}]                             
      for(var i=0; i<Result.length;i++){
          keys = [];
              for(var k in Result[i]){
                keys.push(k);
               }
          for(var k=0;k<keys.length;k++){
                console.log(keys[k]+"="+ Result[i][keys[k]]);
              }
            console.log("key count =" +keys.length);
           } 
     }
```

**[CHECK THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/8725/)**

Comment: again i see you are accessing it by Result[i].ID, here i dont want to specify the key as it is dynamic so wanted to access it by index

Answer (score 0):

Your Result is an array of object, then you must first get an object, and then get the property of your object. This is not a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You array has an object we have to convert that object to array. So converting whole var Result to newResult you can access newResult and it's component through index number

```
    Result = [
          {"ID":1,"Type":"Pyramid","Phase":"One"},
          {"ID":2,"Type":"Pyramid","Phase":"Two"}
        ];
        var newResult = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < Result.length; i++) {
            newResult[i] = [];
            for (var x in Result[i]) {
                 if (Result[i].hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                      newResult[i].push(Result[i][x]);  
                    }
            };
        };
        console.log(newResult);
```

Use newResult instead of Result

You can get ID by newResult[0][0]

**http://jsfiddle.net/LLz1cbok/**

Comment: ok after getting into newResult how do i access each value by index. when i tried this newResult[0][1] i am getting undefined

Comment: have you gone through the code, because its running i tried i am giving you JS Fiddle link wait

Comment: I have added Fiddle Link